# return generic type from generic function

Tags: java, generics, super, return-type

we have a method more or less like the following.
however we currently return List
which in function bla() would return `List<Bar>` at runtime.

I'm looking for a way to make both

```
List<Interface> =  troubleFuction(foo, bar.getCLass());;
```

and

```
List<Bar> = troubleFuction(foo, bar.getCLass());;
```

possible.
basicaly i want it to return List which would be compatible with interface
however this gives the following error

*Type mismatch: cannot convert from `List<capture#3-of ? extends Bar>` to `List<Interface>*`

is there any way to make this return type possible or does runtime erasure make this impossible

```
public <T1 extends Interface, T2 extends Interface> List<"problem"> troubleFunction( T1 in, Class<T2> clazz) {
  return in.doStuffWhichGeneratesAlistOF(clazz)
}

public void bla() {
  Foo foo = new Foo(); // implements interface
  Bar bar = new Bar(); // implements interface
  List<Interface> ifaces = toubleFuction(foo, bar.getCLass());
  List<Bar> mustAlsoWork = toubleFuction(foo, bar.getCLass());
}
```

edit:
in a lot of the existing code base the method is called like

```
List<Bar> result = troubleFunction(List<Interface> list, Bar.class);
```

thus this return type must stay compatible (rewrite/re-factor is not an option)

essentially i want the method to return List`<? super Bar>` if called as

```
troublefunction(foo, Bar.class);
```

and 
`List<? super Foo>` when  called as

```
troublefunction(foo, Bar.class);
```

Comment: In Java a function is called a method.

Comment: Interface is not a reserved word?

Comment: iface is supposed to be a List<Interface>?

Comment: You mean "and List<? super Foo> when called as troublefunction(foo, Foo.class);", right?

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking in situations like this, you need to explicitly pass a Class object in (generically parameterised) which is used for the return value.

However it looks like you've done this already in your case, so would it not work for `troubleFunction` to be declared to return `List<T2>`?  Alternatively, if you want to keep it general then have it return `List<? extends Interface>`.

Answer (score 1):

You're not giving us enough information to really tell what you need to do. For example, you didn't give us the type signature of `doStuffWhichGeneratesAlistOF()` or tell us what it does. And you didn't tell us what the type of the "`in`" argument has to do with all of this.

Sure, it's *possible* to have the return type of a method be generic. For example,

```
public <T extends Interface> List<T> troubleFunction(Interface in, Class<? extends T> clazz) {
  List<T> result = new ArrayList<T>();
  result.add(clazz.newInstance());
  return result;
}
```

And then you could call the method directly like this and it would work (you don't need to specify the type parameter explicitly because it's inferred from the assignment):

```
List<Interface> iface = this.troubleFunction(foo, bar.getCLass());
```

But seeing as how in your code above you return the result of `in.doStuffWhichGeneratesAlistOF(clazz)`, you would probably have to make the return type of that method generic also. But I can't really help you on that because we don't have any information on that method.

Comment: the in function returns an list of instances of class Bar when called as foo.doStuffWhichGeneratesAlistOF(Bar.class)

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, the argument types are looked at before the target type to infer the generic arguments. So, I guess you need to explicitly specify the generic arguments, which I think goes something like this:

```
List<Interface> iface = this.<Interface>troubleFunction(foo, bar.getCLass());
```

where

```
public <T extends Interface> List<T> troubleFunction(
    T in, Class<? extends T> clazz
) {
```

Answer (score 0):

i've looked at this again and the problem was that i wanted to use a 'super' return type 
the signature i was looking for was more or less:

```
 public <T1 extends interface, T2 super T1> List<T2> getAList(Class<T1> clazz);
```

which is not possible